# Lookup column that auto filters bases on site pages.

Tags: lookup-column, filter, form, custom-masterpage, query

I'm building a form that surveys user's opinion of the page the page viewed by the user.

I have a list with a lookup-column that gets the ID from site pages.

I'm looking for the ID to be automatically filtered based on the page the users is on.

What would be the best way to do this.

The form is currently floating on the master page.

Thanks